# Crystal report printer not showing after moving to a new server

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have moved a web site (ASP.NET) from Azure VM to another new Azure VM.
It contains crystal reports and in old server in crystal report viewer, the printer option was working well.(in Chrome)
Means, when click the printer button, the printer showed up. But in the new server, when printer button clicked ,only the PDF printing option is showing up.
I have not done any changes to the web site, but just moved the files to create the new site.
Anyone can help me how to get showed up the printer without any changes done to the web site?

Comment: check printers in new server also all browsers showing same result ?

Comment: Well, I'm confused with browser testing. I have tested locally in Chrome,FireFox, IE and the printer dialog box didn't appear,but Export to PDF.